# google-assistant-demo and googlesamples-assistant-hotword segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, google-aiy, hotword

I tried to install google assistant on raspberry pi3 b+ using these instructions - https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/ - and using GassistPi.

In both cases when I run command

```
google-assistant-demo --project-id 'my-project-id' --device-model-id 'my-device-modelt-id'
```

or

```
googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id 'my-project-id' --device-model-id 'my-device-modelt-id'
```

(where I substitute `'my-project-id'` and `'my-device-modelt-id'` with the data obtained following previous website reported) I obtain "Segmentation Fault".

This error does not occur when I run `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id 'my-project-id' --device-model-id 'my-device-modelt-id'` command.

I tried to search the solution online but I didn't find any suggestion which solve my problem (also upgrade libraries). Can someone help me to solve this segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled api form https://console.developers.google.com ?
Enable API then copy project id and device model id and then use:

**google-assistant-demo --project-id** : 'enter here your project id'
**device-model-id** : 'enter here your devicemodel id'